do dielectric unions preserve continuity or do the two pipes need to be jumpered to preserve continuity?
Scenario: old house (not mine) with a mix of galvanized steel pipe and copper pipe.  Pinhole leak in galvanic pipe, and it was replaced by plumber with a brass nipple and a dielectric union where it connected to the copper.
Concern: has the "bonding" of the piping system now been disrupted?  Should a couple of bronze clamps  be installed on either side of the  union and jumpered with a length of copper wire to ensure continuity?

Dielectric unions are intentional continuity breaks
Putting a bonding jumper around a dielectric union, sadly, is not an option, since it would defeat the continuity-breaking function that the dielectric union was installed to perform.
The only option to provide both AC grounding/bonding and DC isolation would be to put a galvanic isolator device in between the two sections of pipe.  These are used in the marine world to block stray DC currents generated by galvanic action from flowing through grounding conductors while allowing AC to pass.  However, their use in a fixed installation's grounding system would require direct approval from your Authority Having Jurisdiction, as the UL listing category for these devices only countenances their use in the marine environment.

What if the jumper wire were to be attached well away from the union, 12 inches, say, on the less noble side, wouldn't the differential be mitigated somewhat, especially near the threads?

Trying to weigh the danger of lack of bonding continuity against the risk of corrosion, and hoping there's a way to minimize the risk of corrosion while ensuring continuity by positioning the jumper a good distance away from the threads.
